# Align overlapping symbols

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, symbols, positioning

I am trying to produce a "fully connected hexagon" symbol, by using `mathrlap{}` with `wasysym` symbols, specifically,

`\mathrlap{\varhexagon}\mathrlap{\varhexstar}\davidsstar`

produces *almost* what I want, but the hexagon is ever so slightly not centered with the other two symbols it seems.

[image]

How can I get better centered alignment for this? Or possibly making the hexagon slightly larger (or the other two slightly smaller) would fix it?

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\varhexagon}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\varhexstar}{%
\davidsstar}}xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you scale the hexagon a little,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym,stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\scalebox{1.1}{$\varhexagon$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\varhexstar}{%
\davidsstar}}xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `tikz` solution, so that the outer hexagon has the same line thickness as the other lines.

[image]

The call for the above image is `\conhex\quad\conhex[4]\quad\conhex[4.5]`

The optional argument is the radius of the circumcircle (in `pt` units). I set the default at 3.5, which looks about the same size as your intended character.

You could similarly define a command `\conpoly` with 2 arguments, one required: `\conpoly{6}\quad\conpoly{7}\quad\conpoly[5]{8}` would produce the following image:

[image]

The required argument is the number of vertices (2 or more); the optional argument is again the radius.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\conhex}[1][3.5]{\tikz[very thin]{
    \foreach \a in {0,...,4} \foreach \b in {\a,...,5}
    \draw[line cap=round](60*\a+30:#1 pt)--(60*\b+30:#1 pt);
    }}

\newcommand{\conpoly}[2][3.5]{\tikz[very thin]{
    \foreach \a in {1,...,#2} \foreach \b in {\a,...,#2}
    \draw[line cap=round](360*\a/#2+90:#1 pt)--(360*\b/#2+90:#1 pt);
    }}

\begin{document}

\conhex\quad\conhex[4]\quad\conhex[4.5]

\conpoly{6}\quad\conpoly{7}\quad\conpoly[5]{8}

\end{document}
```